# Haproxy capture the request body only if backend gives certain status (504)

Tags: logging, haproxy

In Haproxy I am trying to accomplish the following:

If a certain requests times out on our back-end server and we present a 504 to the person trying to reach our website, only then we want to log the request body.

The following config was tried

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    default_backend webservers
    http-request capture req.body len 10 if { status 500:599 }

backend webservers
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    server apache1 ${APACHE_1_IP}:80 check
```

This however does not work since the status is not available in the http-request capture header rule.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Based on the server response capture the req.body yes or no? It is also fine to always capture the response body but only give it back to the logs if we get a certain status code.

The following does work, but always logs the body which we don't want

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    default_backend webservers
    http-request capture req.body len 10

backend webservers
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    server apache1 ${APACHE_1_IP}:80 check
```